# Need to execute a query only once when accessing the site for the first time

Tags: javascript

I want to execute a javascript query only once when someone trying to access the site.
Say i am trying to access http://www.google.com for the first time i should have the javascript query triggered.

Answer (score 4):

Have your Javascript check for the presence of a [cookie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html). If the user doesn't have your cookie, run your script and add the cookie.